# Java Encapsulation confusion

Tags: java

Got a doubt regarding Encapsulation, don't know whether its a silly question to ask, but was not able to find answer, If i have a pojo class which is serialized,and passed over network, someone can easily hack the object and change its state through setter method, so my case is how encapsulation is actually hiding data from external system?

ex

```
    class TestSeralize implement Serializable{
//some setter
    }
test=new TstSeralize();// passed over network.

//hack test by middleman attack & reset through setter
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the purpose of `Encapsulation`?

> Encapsulation is the technique of making the fields in a class private and providing access to the fields via public methods.
>
> If a field is declared private, it cannot be accessed by anyone outside the class, thereby hiding the fields within the class. For this reason, encapsulation is also referred to as data hiding.

Encapsulation doesn't restrict to call public `setter/getter`. You have to use other techniques such as `encryption`, security tokens etc. to check for any changes made in the middle of the stream.

Please have a look at below links

- [Signing Java Objects for Secure Transfer](http://www.venishjoe.net/2009/10/signing-java-objects-for-secure.html)
- [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you send a serialized object over a network with no integrity protection, it is possible for someone to replace it with a different serialized object and the receiver won't know the difference.  To avoid this, use a network channel with integrity protection, such as TLS.